# What does ** mean in python

Tags: python

I'm confused what one * and two ** does in front of a parameter.

```
def wrapper(*args, **wdargs):
```

Comment: I think that's a typo, it should be `**kwargs`

Comment: jamylak: i think "kwargs" is just a convention, you can use any variable name there.

Answer (score 0):

It means keyword arguments.

eg.

```
func(x, y, foo='a') # where foo is a keyword argument
```

Answer (score 0):

They are used to accept a variable number of arguements.
Check this out : http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/